# Accessing a file from a different GitHub repository

Tags: java, github

Is there a way to import data from different repos?
I have a lambda function in repo A (in a private organsation) that needs to read data from a different repo B in the organisation's GitHub.
I'm periodically checking certificate expiries of various URLs which are stored in repo B. No changes should be made to the repo B, just files read.

The file cannot be just copied over as any new certs added to the file in repo B needs to be checked by the function in repo A when it runs.

The code is using Java.

These repos have other functions and thus I don't think I can use things like subtree or submodule.

Comment: If it's GitHub, can't you just do an HTTP GET of the raw.githubusercontent.com url of a file / files at whichever commitish you want? Can you clarify whether you want to avoid fetching the entire working tree content of whichever commit you want? Ie. Do you want only fetch files that you need and nothing else? Please [edit].

Comment: It's from a private organisation repo so a normal HTTP get can't access the url.

Answer (score 0):

That would need to be managed by a separate program of yours, in charge of:

- going to a local clone of repoB and refreshing its content (`git pull`)
- reading the certificates you need, and checking them with repoA function
- copy the data you want over to repoA
- add and commit in repoA

You can trigger that program:

- periodically.
- on push events on repoB, provided you setup a [webhook](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/about-webhooks) listener.
- from GitHub, in a [GitHub Action workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows).